# The smallest absolute diﬀerence in value between two diﬀerent array elements using brute force

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

- input: an array a[1..n] of real numbers;
- output: the smallest absolute diﬀerence in value between two diﬀerent array elements.

I want a brute force algorithm for the same.

Any one has any idea?

Comment: For each element in the array, loop through the array again (skipping the index of that element), finding the difference, and if it's lower than the 'lowest', then set that as lowest. THanks to Dougal for suggesting.

Comment: @birryree Or just keep track of the minimum thus far as you're looping through. Also, since it's symmetric, you only need to loop over `i` and inner loop over `j > i`.

Comment: @Dougal - yes, that makes more sense (plus tracking the indices of the two elements involved).

Comment: Brute force is almost by definition taking the difference of every possible pair and then finding the lowest. Anything else is not brute force. Basically @birryree 's suggestion except that you can skip the index of that element and all lowe indexes (since you've already compared it to the earlier elements when you processed them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to brute-force it, simply loop over every pair of elements:

```
min = infinity

for i=1 to n-1
    for j = i+1 to n
        if abs(a[i]-a[j]) < min
            min = abs(a[i]-a[j])
```

This takes `O(n^2)` time. You can achieve `O(n log n)` time by first sorting the list:

```
sort(a)
min = infinity

for i = 1 to n-1
    if abs(a[i+1]-a[i]) < min
        min = abs(a[i+1]-a[i])
```

Answer (score 4):

If the elements are sorted, then you might only need to compare each pair of items sequentially:
[1, 3, 6, 7, 28] -> 7-6 gives the smallest distance

To brute force it, I suppose you could subtract each value from each other value (n*n-1) and keep track of which pair is smallest. You would need to make sure you don't subtract the same element from itself, but elements with the same values should be allowable as pairs.

Comment: you only need `n*(n-1)/2`, don't you?